# Convert location of tap in UIWebView into the character tapped

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uilabel, uitextview

I use a `UIWebView` to display text with embedded links in my application. I've got a method that detects taps in the `UIWebView`, but I want to figure out how to detect what character / part of text in the note was tapped.

When a user taps, the text, it'll open a `UITextView` with that same text, and I'd like to place the cursor at the position of the tap.

So far, I've figured out how to get the X and Y position as follows:

```
 NSInteger xInt = [x integerValue];
 NSInteger yInt = [y integerValue] + (int)webView.scrollView.contentOffset.y;
```

I've also got the text as follows:

```
UILabel *noteTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
noteTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:TEXT_FONT_SIZE_LARGE];
noteTextLabel.text = note.text;
```

How would I detect which character was tapped, based on the X and Y position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it, based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621966/how-to-detect-when-uiwebview-starts-selecting-text).

In the `viewController` that is loaded with the `UITextView`, I pass an attribute called `pointForCursor` that's a `CGPoint` with the X and Y as mentioned above.

Then in `viewWillAppear`, I run the following:

```
if (self.pointForCursor.x > 0) {
        NSLog(@"Should have point for cursor");
        UITextPosition *position=[noteTextView closestPositionToPoint:pointForCursor];
        [noteTextView setSelectedTextRange:[noteTextView textRangeFromPosition:position toPosition:position]];
}
```

NOTE: My UIWebView and this UITextView use the same size font, so there weren't any concerns there.

Answer (score 0):

You could embed some javascript /jQuery in the UIWebView to do the click detection (google how to detect clicks in a web page), once you know the div that was tapped, store the contents of it in a know location like a hidden div on the page then extract that using

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getClickedDivContents()"];
```

which would spit of the text of your secret div

Comment: Thanks, but I already knew how to get the X and Y position :)